# Redirect using mod_rewrite and referer (not working properly)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

so, I'm trying to do a rule using mod_rewrite to only show a website when it's coming from another website (based on the referer).

this is the console network log:
[image: console network log]

I have made the following in.htaccess (the mod_rewrite is working and all):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://mybasedomain.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^ https://otherdomain.com/ [R,L]
```

now, I only want people to be able to enter to any page in my domain only if they come from "mybasedomain", otherwise redirect to "otherdomain"

the thing is that I don't see the referer info in the console, and he .htaccess code is not working (always trying to redirect to "otherdomain")

apparently the php file, the italian.php I mean, (which has an script for checking for proxys and stuff) is also stripping the referer (I think).

is there a way I can acomplish this?

thank you.

Comment: _"is there a way I can acomplish this?"_ - no, you can not, because the referrer is absolutely unreliable, as you should be able to research easily enough.

Comment: ok, maybe a different alternative you can suggest? I have control over the 2 domains, but I only want users to be able to see message.html if they came from italian.php,  this can be with parameters, or other values that are might use, the thing is that I don't want users directly accessing message.html